# How do I find the set of limit points of a set in the cofinite topology?

Tags: general-topology

I first considered the case when $X$ is finite. This then means that the set of limit points of any subset of $X$ is empty. I'm stuck with the case when $X$ is infinite. If $A \subseteq X$ is a finite subset, then I can see again that the limit point set is empty. But what if $A$ too were infinite?

$T_f=\{\phi\}\cup\{A \subseteq X : X - A \, \text{is finite} \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ and let $A$ be an infinite subset of $X$.

If $U$ is an open set with $x\in U$ then $U^c$ is finite so that $A-\{x\}\subseteq U^c$ is not possible.

That means that $(A-\{x\})\cap U\neq\varnothing$ allowing us to conclude that $x$ is a limit point of $A$.